# Update specific object elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to update the location for a specific object in my array without altering the original object. In the example below, I change the location using the setCity method, but that also changes the location for the Dragon object. I also can change the animal using the setAnimalType method but that is not the requirements for my project. Can't quite find a solution that uses this type of example.

```
//Define locations
Location location1 = new Location("Seattle","WA");
Location location2 = new Location("Austin", "TX");
Location location3 = new Location("Atlanta", "GA");
   
//Build animal object and set location
Animal animal1 = new Animal("Cat",location1);
Animal animal2 = new Animal("Dog",location2);
Animal animal3 = new Animal("Bunny",location3);    
Animal animal4 = new Animal("Dragon",location1);
        
//Project must use Array
Animal[] animals = new Animal[5];
animals[0] = animal1;
animals[1] = animal2;
animals[2] = animal3;        
animals[3] = animal4;
        
//Update animal[3]'s location to Tacoma
location1.setCity("Tacoma");
        
//Update animal[2] to Unicorn
animal3.setAnimalType("Unicorn");
```

Comment: You have to make a new `Location` object and set the appropriate `Animal` object to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create new objects and set them inside of your array.

There are multiple ways of doing this.

1. Create a new object for each object before storing it inside of the array

```java
//Define locations
Location location1 = new Location("Seattle","WA");
Location location2 = new Location("Austin", "TX");
Location location3 = new Location("Atlanta", "GA");
   
//Build animal object and set location
Animal animal1 = new Animal("Cat",location1);
Animal animal2 = new Animal("Dog",location2);
Animal animal3 = new Animal("Bunny",location3);    
Animal animal4 = new Animal("Dragon",location1);
          
//Project must use Array
Animal[] animals = new Animal[5];
animals[0] = new Animal(animal1);
animals[1] = new Animal(animal2);
animals[2] = new Animal(animal3);        
animals[3] = new Animal(animal4);
          
animals[0].getLocation().setCity("Tacoma");
animals[2].setAnimalType("Unicorn");
```

This implies your `Animal` and `Location` objects should have the following constructors

```java
public class Animal {
    public Animal(Animal toClone) {
        this(toClone.getAnimalType(), new Location(toClone.getLocation())); 
    }
}
```

```java
public class Location {
    public Location(Location toClone) {
        this(toClone.getCity(), toClone.getState());
    }
}
```

2. Create a new object only when you're updating a specific index

```java
//Define locations
Location location1 = new Location("Seattle","WA");
Location location2 = new Location("Austin", "TX");
Location location3 = new Location("Atlanta", "GA");
   
//Build animal object and set location
Animal animal1 = new Animal("Cat",location1);
Animal animal2 = new Animal("Dog",location2);
Animal animal3 = new Animal("Bunny",location3);    
Animal animal4 = new Animal("Dragon",location1);
          
//Project must use Array
Animal[] animals = new Animal[5];
animals[0] = animal1;
animals[1] = animal2;
animals[2] = animal3;        
animals[3] = animal4;
    
Animal existingAnimal = animals[0];
Location existingLocation = existingAnimal.getLocation();

Location newLocation = new Location("Tacoma", existingLocation.getCity());
Animal newAnimal = new Animal(animal.getAnimalType(), newLocation);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're changing the value of location1 which is referenced in both arrays. If you want different references, create different instances.

```
Animal animal1 = new Animal("Cat", new Location("Seattle","WA"));
Animal animal2 = new Animal("Dog", new Location("Austin", "TX"));
Animal animal3 = new Animal("Bunny", new Location("Atlanta", "GA"));    
Animal animal4 = new Animal("Dragon", new Location("Seattle","WA"));
```

Then change locations by:

```
animal1.getLocation().setCity("Tacoma");
```